# can't type '$' in vim command bar

Tags: vim

my vim version info like below

`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May 26 2016 10:31:33)`

and I don't know when(maybe after install some plugin..) that I can't type `$` in vim command bar like below image

I try type `!@#$%` but I can't type `$`

[image]

how should I fix that?

thanks for your time,

regards.

Comment: Does `:verbose cmap $` report anything? (you will have to paste `$` using `<C-R>"`, or start Vim using `vim +"verbose cmap $"`, if you can't type `$` in command mode)

Comment: I can't paste `$` in any way, and I follow `vim +"verbose cmap $"` only find one warning `NERDTree: 1 invalid bookmarks were read. See :help NERDTreeInvalidBookmarks for info.` in command bar.

Comment: @Amadan  thanks for your reply, I check my `~/.vimrc` file and delete `cnoremap $ <end>`, that's my fault :(